# epel-release not found after Ansible run

Tags: ansible

I'm developing my first playbook. I'm using 3 CentOS 8 VMs. Using  Oracle Virtual Box on my local pc with Windows 10, which virtualize an Ansible controller VM and 2 target VM's.

My inventory.txt:

```
# Inventory File
target1 ansible_ssh_pass=osboxes.org ansible_host=192.168.1.106
target2 ansible_ssh_pass=osboxes.org ansible_host=192.168.1.153
```

My playbook-webapp.yaml contains:

```yaml
# Ansible Playbook to install a web application

-
 name: Deploy Web application
 hosts: target1, target2
 remote_user: root
 tasks:
     - name: Install dependencies
       yum: name= {{ item }} state=installed
       with_items:
         - epel-release
         - python
         - python-pi
```

I execute with:

```yaml
ansible-playbook playbook-webapp.yaml -i inventory.txt
```

Output:

```sh
PLAY [Deploy Web application] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target2]
ok: [target1]

TASK [Install dependencies] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => (item=epel-release)
ok: [target2] => (item=epel-release)
ok: [target1] => (item=python)
ok: [target2] => (item=python)
ok: [target1] => (item=python-pip)
ok: [target2] => (item=python-pip)

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
target2                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But when I try to check for my yum repos on target1 node:

```sh
[osboxes@target1 ~]$ yum repolist
repo id                         repo name
appstream                       CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
baseos                          CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS
extras                          CentOS Linux 8 - Extras
```

However, no `epel-release` of some sort is shown, but is set in the ansible task to be installed.

If I try to execute

```sh
[osboxes@ansiblecontroller web_deployment]$ ansible all -m ping -i inventory.txt
```

Output:

```sh
target2 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
target1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: I expect that on my target nodes are installed the dependecies epel_release, python and python but checking with yum repolist on the target nodes they are not installed

Comment: Perhaps you 'targetted' the incorrect VM's?

Comment: I've checked it and I've only those three VMs active now in my Oracle Virtual Box. Is the code I've written right? If yes, probably, the problem is somewhere in my VMs configuration but I don't know where. Thank you anyway !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the package with the [dnf module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html):

```yaml
- name: Install dependencies
  dnf:
    name:
      - epel-release
      - python
      - python-pi
```

Also, a nice approach to manage your systems with Ansible would be to download the operating system, install python3, then package your system again and use that packaged OS for all VM's. This way, the system is as 'bald' as possible, but only includes python3, which is good for Ansible usage.

> no epel-release or other is shown

This is actually quite weird. This sounds like something you should chase. Since we don't know the background details here, I can only guess and guide you in the correct direction.

I am asking myself/you whether you have 'targetted' the correct machine. There are 100 ways to verify whether this is the case. I would do it like this:

```yaml
- shell: touch /tmp/hi
```

Then login at the system, and check whether /tmp/hi exists... if it does, then something fishy is going on.

Check installed packages with:

```sh
rpm -qa | grep -i epel
```

Is it installed?

Also, the `yum.repos.d` should contain the epel repo files

```sh
[vagrant@vm-local-1 ~]$ ls /etc/yum.repos.d/ | grep epel
epel-modular.repo
epel-playground.repo
epel-testing-modular.repo
epel-testing.repo
epel.repo
```

Please let us know.

Comment: I've tried to modify my playbook using `- shell: touch /tmp/hi` and it works and create the  /tmp/hi file in both target node ... so now I've checked that ssh communication is working

Comment: And the epel release file(s), and the command of rpm -qa?

Comment: It's works but only for epel-release installation ... for both python (python and python-pi), dependencies it doesn't work .... `No package <name_of_the_package> available.`  A small step forward .. thank you a lot!

Comment: The name is most likely incorrect. You should use: python3, and/or python3-pip

Answer (score 0):

Following the @Kevin suggestions the right playbook is:

```
# Ansible Playbook to install a web application

-
 name: Deploy Web application
 hosts: target1, target2
 remote_user: root
 tasks:
     - name: Install dependencies
       dnf:
        name:
         - epel-release
         - python3
         - python3-pip
        state: installed
```

To check on the target VMs:

```
 yum repolist
```

or

```
ls /etc/yum.repos.d/ | grep epel
```

and

```
python3 --version
```